# Nothing happens when returning File in IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-11, filecontentresult

I have a method looking like this:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadFile()
{
    // Lots of code
    fileData = myWebService.GetFileBytes();
    return File(fileData, "application/zip", "myZippedFile.zip");
}
```

This method is working fine in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer < 11 in which nothing at all happens. I haven't been able to find anything related to my issue after googling for quite a while so now I turn to you.

Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?

**Edit**
I've recently started to delve deeper into the code and actually looked at the JavaScript calling this method, which looks like this:

```
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
```

This line is not called for IE11 as my browser check fails to recognize that this is actually Internet Explorer and thus starts to execute code that only works for Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Does your IE run on Server or Client? What do the F12 Tools log in Network?

Comment: @T.Glatzer it runs on the Client and the Network logs the file as received.

Comment: Well - seems you have another Problem, which is not in your code. Tried another machine?

Comment: @T.Glatzer, the same thing happens when testing on another machine, yes.

Comment: The error lies in "my browser check" - browser check is evil! (Ask google why)

Comment: @T.Glatzer. Yes indeed it did. For now my browser check looks for Trident, who knows when/if this will change? Time will tell I guess...

Comment: Just to clearify: DON'T DO BROWSERCHECKS! They are the root of all JavaScript evil!